# How to get reddit URL JSON data in android?

Tags: android, logcat, arrays, json

I'm attempting to get a list of URL's from a subreddit in order to load them into universal image loader for viewing pleasure. However, I cannot figure out where my query is going wrong. Plus, I'm not familiar with android studio's logcat as compared to eclipses logcat, so I'm not exactly sure where to look for my debugging responses.

Here's the query method:

```
        public void queryReddit()
    {
        // Prepare your search string to be put in a URL
        // It might have reserved characters or something
//        String urlString = "";
//        try {
//            urlString = URLEncoder.encode(searchString, "UTF-8");
//        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
//
//            // if this fails for some reason, let the user know why
//            e.printStackTrace();
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//        }

        // Create a client to perform networking
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        // 11. start progress bar
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);


        // Have the client get a JSONArray of data
        // and define how to respond
        client.get("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/.json",
                new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        // 11. stop progress bar
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                        // Display a "Toast" message
                        // to announce your success
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//                        // 8. For now, just log results
//                        Log.d("omg android", jsonObject.toString());


                        try
                        {
                            Log.d("go reddit yay", jsonObject.toString());
                            JSONObject testingData = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("data");
                            JSONArray testingChildren = (JSONArray) testingData.get("children");
                            JSONObject testingLogData = (JSONObject) testingChildren.get(0);
                            JSONArray children = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("children");
                            JSONObject logData = (JSONObject) children.get(0);
                            Log.d("go reddit yay", logData.getString("url"));
                            Log.d("go reddit yay", testingLogData.getString("url"));
                            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) children.get(i);



                                if(data.getString("url") != null)
                                {
                                    System.out.println(data.getString("url"));
                                }
                                //if the url field exists and it's a picture that univ image loader understands then add it
                                if(data.getString("url") != null && data.getString("url").substring(data.getString("url").length()-3).equals("png") ||
                                        data.getString("url").substring(data.getString("url").length()-3).equals("jpg"))
                                {
                                    imageUrls.add(data.getString("url"));
                                    System.out.println(data.getString("url"));
                                }

                                //TODO I found this error: this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
                            }
                            mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        //TODO Might want to put all this data in a try catch block and do it right here.
                        // update the data in your custom method.
                        //updateData()
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable throwable, JSONObject error)
                    {
                        // 11. stop progress bar
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                        // Display a "Toast" message
                        // to announce the failure
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + statusCode + " " + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Log error message
                        // to help solve any problems
                        Log.e("omg android", statusCode + " " + throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
```

Within the try catch block, the only logged information that ends up being sent to logcat is the first line, Log.d("go reddit yay", jsonObject.toString());

I can't find the responses from the other log calls which is very strange to me.

Here's the response from the first log call:

```
06-17 06:35:29.324  17133-17133/.wallpaper D/absfr﹕ {"data":{"after":"t3_2823ou","children":[{"data":{"media_embed":{},"author_flair_css_class":null,"score":503,"created_utc":1402931529,"clicked":false,"visited":false,"id":"28a94k","author":"JamesBDW","title":"Any Bronson fans? [1920x1080]","over_18":false,"created":1402960329,"name":"t3_28a94k","selftext_html":null,"domain":"i.imgur.com","author_flair_text":null,"secure_media":null,"num_reports":null,"edited":false,"stickied":false,"link_flair_text":null,"link_flair_css_class":null,"saved":false,"secure_media_embed":{},"subreddit_id":"t5_2qmjl","distinguished":null,"gilded":0,"url":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/Hq1fcSm.jpg","banned_by":null,"subreddit":"wallpaper","is_self":false,"num_comments":31,"approved_by":null,"thumbnail":"http:\/\/a.thumbs.redditmedia.com\/Dh2iU7Q0rpFogkWt.jpg","permalink":"\/r\/wallpaper\/comments\/28a94k\/any_bronson_fans_1920x1080\/","hidden":false,"likes":null,"downs":188,"ups":691,"selftext":"","media":null},"kind":"t3"},{"data":{"media_embed":{},"author_flair_css_class":null,"score":8,"created_utc":1402989714,"clicked":false,"visited":false,"id":"28cnyn","author":"ZadocPaet","title":"Active Dunes on Mars (OS) [1024x768]","over_18":false,"created":1403018514,"name":"t3_28cnyn","selftext_html":null,"domain":"nasa.gov","author_flair_text":null,"secure_media":null,"num_reports":null,"edited":false,"stickied":false,"link_flair_text":null,"link_flair_css_class":null,"saved":false,"secure_media_embed":{},"subreddit_id":"t5_2qmjl","distinguished":null,"gilded":0,"url":"http:\/\/www.nasa.gov\/sites\/default\/files\/styles\/1024x768_autoletterbox\/public\/pia18244.jpg","banned_by":null,"subreddit":"wallpaper","is_self":false,"num_comments":1,"approved_by":null,"thumbnail":"http:\/\/a.thumbs.redditmedia.com\/dFTBquSWiMSjK0aZ.jpg","permalink":"\/r\/wallpaper\/comments\/28cnyn\/active_dunes_on_mars_os_1024x768\/","hidden":false,"likes":null,"downs":3,"ups":11,"selftext":"","media":null},"kind":"t3"},{"data":{"media_embed":{"content":"&lt;iframe class=\"embedly-embed\" src=\"\/\/cdn.embedly.com\/widgets\/media.html?src=http%3A%2F%2Fimgur.com%2Fa%2F0jeZf%2Fembed&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fimgur.com%2Fa%2F0jeZf&amp;image=http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2F2PdUiuE.jpg&amp;key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=text%2Fhtml&amp;schema=imgur\" width=\"550\" height=\"550\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;\/iframe&gt;","scrolling":false,"height":550,"width":550},"author_flair_css_class":null,"score":1,"created_utc":1403004127,"clicked":false,"visited":false,"id":"28czid","author":"smessies","title":"I found a wallpaper album full of iconic design chairs. I tought there were some important ones missing so i started adding some myself. work in progress! [1920x1200]","over_18":false,"created":1403032927,"name":"t3_28czid","selftext_html":null,"domain":"imgur.com","author_flair_text":null,"secure_media":null,"num_reports":null,"edited":false,"stickied":false,"link_flair_text":null,"link_flair_css_class":null,"saved":false,"secure_media_embed":{},"subreddit_id":"t5_2qmjl","distinguished":null,"gilded":0,"url":"http:\/\/imgur.com\/a\/0jeZf","banned_by":null,"subreddit":"wallpaper","is_self":false,"num_comments":0,"approved_by":null,"thumbnail":"http:\/\/b.thumbs.redditmedia.com\/GYaN5fyJfY8fI8xE.jpg","permalink":"\/r\/wallpaper\/comments\/28czid\/i_found_a_wallpaper_album_full_of_iconic_design\/","hidden":false,"likes":null,"downs":0,"ups":1,"selftext":"","media":{"type":"imgur.com","oembed":{"thumbnail_height":1200,"author_url":"http:\/\/imgur.com\/user\/smessies","width":550,"type":"rich","version":"1.0","thumbnail_url":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/2PdUiuE.jpg","thumbnail_width":1920,"title":"imgur: the simple image sharer","height":550,"description":"Imgur is home to the web's most popular image content, curated in real time by a dedicated community through commenting, voting and sharing.","author_name":"smessies","html":"&lt;iframe class=\"embedly-embed\" src=\"\/\/cdn.embedly.com\/widgets\/media.html?src=http%3A%2F%2Fimgur.com%2Fa%2F0jeZf%2Fembed&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fimgur.com%2F
```

no idea what to do.

One last debugging info is that the toast for the onSuccess method does appear, so it is clearly successful in it's query, I'm just doing something wrong in interpreting the data.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems like a statement after the first `Log.d("go reddit yay", ...);` call throws an exception which you can't see.

Try replacing your exception handling code:

```
} catch (JSONException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

with this:

```
} catch (Throwable t)
{
    Log.e("omg android", "Exception in onSuccess()", t);
}
```

and check if any exceptions are logged.